# DB21034E IBM db2 Error

Tags: unix, db2

I am trying to execute db2 command in unix command prompt `db2 -tvsf UC_Repair_History.sql` it is giving me below error. I checked in the file only insert statements are there.I have executed the similar file those are execute this one is not executed. ERROR is given below

`DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "�".
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  SQLSTATE=42601`

Please any one help

Comment: Are you using Windows? different coding? open the file in a text editor like Notepad++ and check the document. You must probably have a weird character. Then encoding and end line character could be the problem.

Comment: Text encoding are in utf-8 format. these scripts are in Linux machine.

Comment: Have you opened the file in vi? there should be a character not valid in the current encoding, such as: çáéíóúñ£µè§

Answer (score 3):

When performing a copy&paste e.g. from Word typographic quotes might get used which the DB2 CLI does not understand. Depending on the font it might be hard to spot the difference. In the following the first select statement was copied from Word, in the second statement I retyped the quotation marks:

```
db2 => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA='SAPSR3'
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'SAPSR3'" was found following "RE
TABSCHEMA=’S".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".
SQLSTATE=42601

db2 => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA='SAPSR3'

1
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.
```